# The unreadable direction

Tags: riddle

Here is my first riddle:

> I help people speak, but do not speak myself, nor can I be read like a book.
>      4 letters on my tag.
>      I provide direction to an object.
>      Used by golfers and designed for them.
>      What am I?

Once again, this is my first riddle, so comment if this needs to be more descriptive.

Hint 1:

> "Used by golfers and designed for them" does not refer to the sport of golf.

Hint 2:

> Look for golf on the stack exchange websites.

Please include if you used the hints in your answers.

Comment: how can this be your first riddle "once again" ?

Comment: @user3453281 [It doesn't mean that.](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/38320/48331)

Comment: He is using 'once again' to re-state something. Like "I repeat, this is my first riddle"

Comment: I don't understand why this has got so many downvotes. Looks like a nice riddle to me (especially the golf line!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be

> Code

I help people speak, but do not speak myself, nor can I be read like a book.

> Code is a language, people can speak it or the execution of the code can lead to understandable 'speak'. But it can't be read like a book directly.

4 letters on my tag.

> Code is 4 letters long

I provide direction to an object.

> A programming object can only perform actions if coded

Used by golfers and designed for them.

> Code-golf

And yes, I used your two hints!

Comment: Good answer! Too bad you had to use the hints though.

Comment: *Good* code can be read pretty much like a book, depending on the language.

Comment: Some of my code certainly looks like a horror story

Answer (score 3):

Answer:

> Flag

I help people speak, but do not speak myself, nor can I be read like a book.

> Semaphore uses flags to communicate

4 letters on my tag.

> Flag is four letters long

I provide direction to an object.

> Flags mark locations and also provide direction of the wind? I'm not totally sure about the "to an object" part of this, unless it's connected to the next line

Used by golfers and designed for them.

> Flags are used in golf to mark the hole. I don't think flags were originally designed for golf use, so the "designed for them" is another part I'm not quite sure about.

Comment: This is not even the answer I was thinking of, but it is still a very good one!

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

> Sign

I help people speak, but do not speak myself, nor can I be read like a book.

> Signs help people communicate, but is not a language used commonly in books.

4 letters on my tag.

> The word sign contains of four letters

I provide direction to an object.

> Direction signs are often used to direct people to an object or a location

Used by golfers and designed for them.

> Every golf hole has a tee sign marking the length and par of the hole. Could also relate to the hand held quiet signs often used in golf tournaments.

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a bit of a stretch for the the first clue but what about:

> Link

I help people speak, but do not speak myself, nor can I be read like a book.

> This one is kind of a stretch as it only kind of helps people speak by allowing them to reference other content. It can't speak or be read like a book, though.

4 letters on my tag.

> Link is 4 letters long AND a hyperlink is created with an HTML tag <a>

I provide direction to an object.

> A hyperlink can be assigned to objects like images and will redirect the user to another page.

Used by golfers and designed for them.

> Golf courses are commonly referred to as links although that's [technically](http://www.pga.com/golf-instruction/instruction-feature/fundamentals/golf-glossary-and-golf-terms#l) only accurate if it's built on land reclaimed from the ocean.